# (Help)AndEngine - Using Move on touch

Tags: touch, andengine, sprite, move

Hey guys im following this code

```
final AnimatedSprite mySprite = new AnimatedSprite(100, 220, this.mySpriteTextureRegion) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        int eventaction = event.getAction(); 

                    float X = event.getX();
                    float Y = event.getY();

                    switch (eventaction) {
                       case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                       case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                            this.setPosition(X, Y);
                            break;}
                       case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                    }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

but using Sprite not AnimatedSprite

but when i test it on my cellphone the sprite dont move...

What im doing wrong ??

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing these?

```
registerTouchArea(mySprite);
setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```